# 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' when trying to convert KerasTensor to NumPy array - how to fix?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I'm working on a deep learning project using Keras, and I'm trying to convert a KerasTensor object to a NumPy array using the numpy() method, but I'm getting an AttributeError:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Define the shape of the input tensor
input_shape = (128, 128, 1)

# Create an input tensor with the specified shape
input_tensor = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Create a model that uses the input tensor
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_tensor)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
output_tensor = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

print(type(output_tensor)) # <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>

# Convert the output tensor to a numpy array
print(type(output_tensor.numpy())) # AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
print(type(tf.keras.backend.eval(output_tensor))) #AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`
```

I've seen other people use the numpy() method successfully in similar situations, so I'm not sure what's causing this error. Can anyone help me understand why this error is occurring, and how I can fix it?

Here's some additional context that might be helpful:

- I'm using Keras with TensorFlow 2.12.0 as the backend.

Comment: Please add how you defined `input_tensor`. KerasTensors are just placeholders so there is nothing to evaluate. They do not hold any specific value.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a KerasTensor object with shape (None, 128, 128, 1) that I need to pass to an OpenCV function. However, I'm having trouble converting the KerasTensor to either a numpy array or a TensorFlow EagerTensor that can be accepted by the function. 
The input_tensor initially has the shape (128, 128, 1) and belongs to the class 'numpy.ndarray'. After passing it through the coder-decoder network, the output tensor has the same shape (128, 128, 1), but now belongs to the class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'.

Comment: Then you need to add those coder-decoder networks and how you pass that array to the models. You don't get a KerasTensor from predict method. Right now it is too abstract.

Comment: I will pass the `input_tensor` through the encoder-decoder network and it will give me an `output_tensor` of type `KerasTensor`. I want to convert this `output_tensor` into a `numpy array` or a `EagerTensor` so that I can pass it to an OpenCV function.
I have edited the post and added a simplified example of what I want to do.